# How read large csv file located in other computer with pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, ssh, spark-structured-streaming

I want to read daily a large file with Pyspark. This large file is located on another computer and I have only SSH access to this computer.

How can I read this file with Pyspark?

And as I say I want to read daily a new file that saves on this remote computer. How can delete the file after reading and finding a new file in the default path?